# QAudioFormat. Undefined reference to '_imp_....'

Tags: c++, qt, qtmultimedia

I'm using Qt 5.1.1, Qt Creator 2.8.1 on Win7. When I compile program I get lots of this type errors:

*.cpp:85: undefined reference to `*imp*__ZN12QAudioFormatC1Ev'

When I double click to them It refers to this part of code:

```
 QAudioFormat format;
 format.setSampleRate(channel->payloadType().clockrate());
 format.setChannelCount(channel->payloadType().channels());
 format.setSampleSize(16);
 format.setCodec("audio/pcm");
 format.setByteOrder(QAudioFormat::LittleEndian);
 format.setSampleType(QAudioFormat::SignedInt);
```

My .pro file:

```
...
QT += core gui network xml multimedia
CONFIG += mobility
MOBILITY += multimedia
...
```

Where is my error? Thank you before hand.

Comment: You probably need to link with a Qt library of some sort.

Comment: There is: QT += core gui network xml multimedia

Comment: did you ``#include <QAudioFormat>``?

Comment: I did, the same error...

Comment: The only thing I can think of is to `clean` the project, run `qmake` again, and then build the project. You're linking to the correct `QT` directive, so unless it's not built the Makefile correctly there shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Looks like you're linking to an incompatible library version. Qt 4.x is not binary compatible with Qt5.x but minor versions are supposed to be. Also, libraries compiled with different compilers are not binary compatible. i.e. MinGW compiled libraries will not link in with MSVC linker, nor vice versa

Comment: I did, all works, thank you...